# Remove duplicated fields in RDD from input data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

my input csv data, some rows contains repeated fields or some missing fields, from this data i want to remove the duplicate fields from each row and then all rows should contain all the fields, with value as NULL is wherever it does not contain fields.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? are you having any specific problem or you are just looking for someone to show you solution?

Comment: @Pushkr, I tried this, by iterating through each row and get the fields based on Key, if the key repeats again ignore it and if doesnot have any of the key populate it as null. but my data set is huge and also sometimes in a row it can 30 to 40 duplicate K:V pairs...so iterating through all the fields and rows is a bad design in terms of performance...so wanted suggestions on the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def transform(line):
    """
    >>> s = 'id:111|name:dave|age:33|city:london'
    >>> transform(s)
    ('id:111', {'age': '33', 'name': 'dave', 'city': 'london'})
    """
    bits = line.split("|")
    key = bits[0]
    pairs = [v.split(":") for v in bits[1:]]
    return key, {kv[0].strip(): kv[1].strip() for kv in pairs if len(kv) == 2}

rdd = (sc
    .textFile("/tmp/sample")
    .map(transform))
```

Find keys:

```
from operator import attrgetter

keys = rdd.values().flatMap(lambda d: d.keys()).distinct().collect()
```

Create data frame:

```
df = rdd.toDF(["id", "map"])
```

And expand:

```
df.select(["id"] + [df["map"][k] for k in keys]).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that you have `rdd` already from the text file. I create one here:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(u'id:111', u'name:dave', u'dept:marketing', u'age:33', u'city:london'),
 (u'id:123', u'name:jhon', u'dept:hr', u'city:newyork'),
 (u'id:100', u'name:peter', u'dept:marketing', u'name:peter', u'age:30', u'city:london'),
 (u'id:222', u'name:smith', u'dept:finance', u'city:boston'),
 (u'id:234', u'name:peter', u'dept:service', u'name:peter', u'dept:service', u'age:32', u'city:richmond')])
```

I just make the function to map the `rdd` into `key` and `value` pair and also remove the duplicated one

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def split_to_dict(l):
    l = list(set(l)) # drop duplicate here
    kv_list = []
    for e in l:
        k, v = e.split(':')
        kv_list.append({'key': k, 'value': v})
    return kv_list

rdd_map = rdd.flatMap(lambda l: split_to_dict(l)).map(lambda x: Row(**x))
df = rdd_map.toDF()
```

**Output** example of first 5 rows

```
+----+---------+
| key|    value|
+----+---------+
|city|   london|
|dept|marketing|
|name|     dave|
| age|       33|
|  id|      111|
+----+---------+
```